# sql search with join returning too much

Tags: php, sql

The problem is that when i do a search i get the all the orders that have a match with the search string.

I need to get a match if only a single condition is true not all of them

By that i mean:
if i search for "Hans" i want to get an order that has a joined user with either user_last_name, user_name, user_address etc. that contains the string value. It does not need to contain "Hans" in all of them.

What i want is that i only get the orders, that have have a certain restaurant_id.
I dont understand what i do wrong because i include WHERE restaurant_fk = :restaurant_id
So wouldnt that filter the orders to only contain the ones with the specific restaurant_id?

```
<?php

require_once __DIR__ . '/../_.php';

session_start();
try {
    $json = file_get_contents('php://input');
    $data = json_decode($json);

    $db = _db();
    $restaurant_id = $data->restaurant_id;
    $search = $data->search;

    $q = $db->prepare(
        'SELECT orders.*, users2.user_name, users2.user_last_name, users2.user_address, users2.user_city, users2.user_zip
            FROM orders
            JOIN users2 ON orders.user_fk = users2.user_id
            WHERE restaurant_fk = :restaurant_id
            AND users2.user_name LIKE :search
            OR users2.user_last_name LIKE :search
            OR users2.user_address LIKE :search
            ORDER BY orders.created_at DESC'
    );

    $q->bindValue(':restaurant_id', $restaurant_id);
    $q->bindValue(':search', "%{$search}%");
    $q->execute();
    $orders = $q->fetchAll();
    echo json_encode(['orders' => $orders]);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    try {
        if (!$e->getCode() || !$e->getMessage()) {
            throw new Exception();
        }
        var_dump($e);
        http_response_code($e->getCode());
        echo json_encode(['info' => $e->getMessage()]);
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        http_response_code(500);
        echo json_encode($ex);
    }
}
```

User table structure
[image: users2 table]

Orders table structure
[image: orders table]

Comment: that is what join makes, it joins when there are twio or more rows that fit together it shows all combinations, it is your joib to see if you can use rwonumber or GROUP BY tpo reduce ot to one row only

Comment: `AND` and `OR` have an order of precedence similar to `*` and `+` respectively. Which means that you need brackets around the OR parts; `x AND a OR B OR c` is effectively `(x AND a) OR b OR c` but you appear to want `x AND (a OR b OR c)`

Comment: @nbk Umm, the issue is actually the where clause.

Comment: Your edit is confusing. Please include example data and desired results, to demonstrate what you do and do not want to happen; [mre]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952)

Answer (score 1):

To constraint the search to a specific restaurant_id, you need to group the `OR` conditions together using parentheses, so that the entire search condition is evaluated together for the specified restaurant_id.

Your `WHERE` clause should look like this:

```
WHERE restaurant_fk = :restaurant_id
AND (
    users2.user_name LIKE :search
    OR users2.user_last_name LIKE :search
    OR users2.user_address LIKE :search
)
```

In SQL, the `AND` operator has [higher precedence](https://ramkedem.com/en/sql-server-and-or/) than the `OR` operator, which means that `AND` operations are evaluated before `OR` operations.

Comment: But i need the search to give a result if any of the LIKE is true

Comment: @SomaJuice Have you tried it?

Comment: yes i tried and i got empy [] back

Comment: This is checking to see if both the first condition is true and the second condition is true, (the second condition will be true if any of the conditions within the parenthesis return true).

Comment: If you were returned an empty array it means either there were no records that matched your search, the values your submitting to the query are wrong, or the LIKE clause doesn't work how you think it does. I would suggest you do some debugging.

Comment: @SomaJuice This is why a [mre] is ***extremely*** important; [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952) *(Please actually read these links and edit your question appropriately, with example data and desired results.)*

Comment: Thanks for that, i will strive for better examples, i updated the edit to more clearly explain what it is i want

Comment: @Jacob true there is nothing that matches the query. I made some confusion it seems like, and edited the post.

Comment: Depending on your DBMS you might need to account for case sensitivity (just convert everything to lowercase using `LOWER` or use `ILIKE` if you're using PostgreSQL).